# Reg adding data to an existing XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have to parse an xml file & modify the data in a particular tag using Python.  I'm using Element Tree to do this. I'm able to parse & reach the required tag. But I'm not able to modify the value. I'm not sure if Element Tree is okay or if I should use TreeBuilder for this.

As you can see below I just want to replace the Not Executed under **Verdict** with a string value.

```
-<Procedure> 
    <PreCondition>PRECONDITION: - ECU in extended diagnostic session (zz = 0x03)     </PreCondition>
    <PostCondition/> 
    <ProcedureID>428495</ProcedureID> 
    <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
    <CID>-1</CID> 
    <**Verdict** Writable="true">NotExecuted</Verdict>  
</Procedure>

import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

X_tree = etree.parse('DIAGNOSTIC SERVER.xml')
X_root = X_tree.getroot()

ATC_Name = X_root.iterfind('TestOrder//TestOrder//TestSuite//')

try:
    while(1):
        temp = ATC_Name.next()              
        if temp.tag == 'ProcedureID' and temp.text == str(TestCase_Id[j].text).split('-')[1]:
            ATC_Name.next()
            ATC_Name.next()
            ATC_Name.next().text = 'Pass' <--This is what I want to do   
            ATC_Name.close()
            break
except:
            print sys.exc_info()
```

I believe my approach is wrong. Kindly guide me with right pointers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better switch to [lxml](http://lxml.de) so that you can use the "unlimited" power of [`xpath`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

The idea is to use the following `xpath` expression:

```
//Procedure[ProcedureID/text()="%d"]/Verdict
```

where `%d` placeholder is substituted with the appropriate procedure id via [string formatting operation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

The xpath expression finds the appropriate `Verdict` tag which you can set `text` on:

```
from lxml import etree

data = """<Procedure>
    <PreCondition>PRECONDITION: - ECU in extended diagnostic session (zz = 0x03)     </PreCondition>
    <PostCondition/>
    <ProcedureID>428495</ProcedureID>
    <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
    <CID>-1</CID>
    <Verdict Writable="true">NotExecuted</Verdict>
</Procedure>"""

ID = 428495
tree = etree.fromstring(data)
verdict = tree.xpath('//Procedure[ProcedureID/text()="%d"]/Verdict' % ID)[0]
verdict.text = 'test'

print etree.tostring(tree)
```

prints:

```
<Procedure>
    <PreCondition>PRECONDITION: - ECU in extended diagnostic session (zz = 0x03)     </PreCondition>
    <PostCondition/>
    <ProcedureID>428495</ProcedureID>
    <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
    <CID>-1</CID>
    <Verdict Writable="true">test</Verdict>
</Procedure>
```

Comment: lxml and xpath are a great solution to the problem, but I would quibble with the xpath because it assumes an ordering of the siblings that may not be valid in the original docs. How about selecting the parent Procedure and then finding its child Verdict like: `'//Procedure[ProcedureID/text()="%d"]/Verdict'`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

root=et.parse(xmldata).getroot()
s=root.find('Verdict')
s.text='Your string'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using ElementTree.    See [*Modifying an XML File*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et


tree = et.parse('prison.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print root.find('Verdict').text #before update
root.find('Verdict').text = 'Executed'

tree.write('prison.xml')
```

Comment: Won't work. The problem is that the OP wants to change the `Verdict` for an appropriate `ProcedureID`.

Comment: @alecxe He can still leverage this. He said he is already able to get to the specific tag, and just needs help modifying.